# Копировать строку таблицы в несколько input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как это сделать за одну вставку CTRL+v ? И как можно проще :)
[Видео](https://i.imgur.com/PeiqJlR.gifv) надеюсь прояснит чего хочу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно на один инпут повесить обработчик события onpaste. это событие сработает при cntl + V на инпуте

```
$("input").bind('paste', function (event) {

  var $this = $(this); 

  setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert($this.val()); //вставленное значение,  теперь его можно добавить в другие инпуты
  },0); 
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, Сергей. И как обработчик получит данные из буфера обмена ?

Comment: Хм, об этом не подумал )  сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: переписал ответ, надеюсь, это то, что нужно

Comment: Спасибо , Сергей. Вы мне очень помогли. Благодарен.